What $n$ would make $ \gcd _{k\ge1 }\left\{\dbinom{m+(k-1)\cdot n}{k}\right\}=1 \ \forall m \in \mathbb{N}$
This is a generalisation of this question.

Construct the sequence $a_n$
$$ a_n =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \gcd _{k\ge1 }\left\{\dbinom{m+(k-1)\cdot n}{k}\right\}=1 \ \forall m \in \mathbb{N} \\
\min{m }: \gcd _{k\ge1 }\left\{\dbinom{m+(k-1)\cdot n}{k}\right\}>1,  & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
It's challenging to determine definitively whether the gcd will ever exceed $1$ for a given $n$. However, we know that $a_1=0$ and for any positive integer $m$ where $N_m$ represents the largest power of a prime factor dividing $m$, the GCD of all binomial coefficients $\binom{m + (k - 1)n}{k}$ for $k = 1$ to $N_m$ is always 1.
import math 

for m in range (1,101):
    a=m

          
    for k in range (1,20_001):
        math.gcd(a, math.comb(m+k-1,k))
        if math.gcd(a, math.comb(m+k-1,k))==1:
            print(f"{k},"  )
            break
            

        a=math.gcd(a, math.comb(m+k-1,k))
        if k==20_000:
            print("for m=" f"{m}" " need more k")  

this code will give the first 100 $N_m$.

$a_2=2$ as proved it this previous question. Determining $a_n$
for $n >2$ seems difficult. another question is: If $a_n >0$ what is  $\gcd _{k\ge1 }\left\{\dbinom{m+(k-1)\cdot n}{k}\right\}$ for the min $m$?
It seems that $a_3=2, a_4=3$

Construct the sequence $b_n$ where $b_n =0$ if $\gcd _{k\ge1 }\left\{\dbinom{m+(k-1)\cdot n}{k}\right\}=1 \ \forall m \in \mathbb{N}$, $b_n =$ the number of $m$ such that  $\gcd _{k\ge1 }\left\{\dbinom{m+(k-1)\cdot n}{k}\right\}>1$ (for example $b_2=1$ because $m=2$ is the only case for such property ) if there exist infinite such $m$ then $b_n=-1$.
Another question is How to calculate $b_n$?
